# how to integrate facebook like button in android

Tags: android

I've tried with webview but it not work. I search something more simple than do "like" to my facebook app when user clicks a button in android application I'm developing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794677/facebook-like-button-in-android-application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917976/facebook-like-button-implementation-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690345/facebook-like-button-in-android-app

Comment: check this post, there is well-formed library to solve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23853937/1891118

Answer (score 0):

I got Solutions, use this for getting fb like button -https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.